# How do I change the background color with <type color>?

Tags: class, click, background-color

Only divs with id are clicking, div with class names are not clicking. 
By clicking on div with id, you need to change the color. Class divs do not have to be clicked and they do not have to change their color. I added it to imput type color class, so it does not click also.
If I try document.getElementByID ("backgroundcolor"). Value; works normally 
if I try document.getElementsByClassName ("backgroundcolor"). value; does not work.
I need to call the ByClassName function(color), but it does not work, Ideas?

```
#divid{
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}



.divclass{
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```
<input type="color" class="backgroundcolor" onchange="BackgroundColor()">

<div  class="divclass">
</div>


<div  id="divid">
</div>
```

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId;

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
        if (e.target.id) alert(this.id);
        clickedDivId = this.id;
        e.stopPropagation();
    };
}  


function BackgroundColor(){
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundcolor").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundColor = x;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundcolor")[0].value;